# Struggling with oneOf in selecting subschemas

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am just having a very hard time getting oneOf to work. Reading about seems straightforward but getting it to work just seems so hard. I just don't have any idea why it does not work for this setup. Here is what I want to accomplish. First, I have a schema which should be able to produce different names depending on the type of data structure. If it is a simple array, then it should be productCodesList with its properties, otherwise it should be productsArray with it's properties.

```
            {
            "productCodesList":{
             "codesIndex": 0,
             "productCodes": [1]
            }

            }

           {
            "productsArray": {
            "productsListIndex":0,
            "productCodesArray": [ [] ]
           } 
          }


   //This works, don't really know what's going on!
   {
      "productCodesList": {
      "productCodes":0,
     "productCodesArray": [ [] ]

   } 
  }
          //This works though, I specify minItems:1

          {
            "productCodesList": {
             "codesIndex":0,
             "productCodes": [  ]
            } 
          }



          {
           "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
            "title": "This my my attempt",
            "additionalProperties":false,
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["productCodes"],
           "properties": {
             "productCodesList": {
             "type":"object",
             "additionalProperties":false,
             "codesIndex": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "productCodes": {
               "type": "array",
               "minItems": 1,
                "items": {
                 "type": "integer"
               }
             }
           },
           "productsArray": {
            "required":["productCodesArray"],
            "type": "object",
            "productsListIndex": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "productCodesArray": {
              "type": "array",
              "minItems": 1,
              "items": {
                "type": "array",
                "minItems": 1,
                "items": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "oneOf": [
          { "type": "object", "required": ["productCodesList"] },
          { "type": "object", "required": ["productsArray"] }
        ]
      }
```

I simply want to pick one of the formats but it's complaining that I am missing
Required properties are missing from object: productCodes.

Answer (score 0):

You have `"required": ["productCodes"]` at the top of your schema.